# Webview is taking almost 80% of the CPU

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I am trying to login to a webpage using Javascript for my app but after successful login I want to load a page which will display the **ExamSeatingPlan**. The app is working fine its loading the required page after successful login but its almost taking **80%** of **CPU**. I think I didn't implement **onPageFinished** right.It will be really helpful if you guys help me solve the problem

Thanks.

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.ebad.badwae;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    final String url = "http://111.68.99.8/StudentProfile/";
    final String urlwanttoload = "http://111.68.99.8/StudentProfile/ExamSeatingPlan.aspx";
    WebView view;
    boolean loaded;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        view = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        WebSettings webSettings = view.getSettings();

        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        view.loadUrl(url);


        view.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView views, String urls) {
                view.loadUrl("javascript: {" + "document.getElementById('ctl00_Body_ENROLLMENTTextBox_tb').value = '" + "01-134121-061" + "';" +
                        "document.getElementById('ctl00_Body_PasswordTextBox_tb').value = '" + "123456789" + "';" +
                        "document.getElementsByName('ctl00$Body$LoginButton')[0].click();" + "};");

                onPageFinishede(views, urls);

            }


            public void onPageFinishede(WebView views, String urls) {
                if (!loaded) {
                    views.loadUrl(urlwanttoload);
                    loaded = true;
                }
            }

        });

    }

}
```

Comment: Remove "onPageFinished(views, urls);" inside your onPageFinished method that you override.  You don't need to call the super of that method.  If you did need to, then it would be super.onPageFinished(views,urls);

Comment: @tim.paetz I am calling an other method to load the page that will display the data I need in **onPageFinishede(views, urls);**